# Simplify the following binary logic expressions - Can this be simplyfied?

Tags: c++, binary, xor

This may be very easy for you, but I have trouble with it.
Given the following binary expression, can this be simplified ?

I'm wondering if I should put parenthesis, and in what order I should do the XORs to simplify this expression.

```
res = a ^ b ^ a ^ c ^ b
```

Thanks!

Comment: not sure, but `res = c` no?

Comment: `^` is commutative so rearrange to `res = a ^ a ^ b ^ b ^ c;`. Then `x ^ x == 0` so remove repeated values to get `res = 0 ^ 0 ^ c;`. Then `0 ^ x == x` so remove zeros to get `res = c;` Homework? Fairly unrealistic question.